How is yield calculated for a portfolio?
If you have a portfolio of US government bonds and treasury futures, and you want to calculate the yield of the portfolio, how would you do this?
Would you say $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i y_i$ where $w_i$ is the value-weight of each security and $y_i$ its yield? What about the treasury futures for whom $w_i = 0$?

Once you have the YTM for each bond, calculate the weighted average yield based on the proportion of each bond’s market value relative to the total market value of all bonds in the portfolio.
$PortfolioYield = \sum w_i YTM_{i}$,
where $w_i =\frac{MarketValueBond_{i}}{TotalMarketValue}$.
When dealing with treasury futures, you should calculate implied yield of the contract using price of treasure contract. As you have market value of future contracts and their corresponding implied yields you can compute weighted average implied yield for future contracts, as described above for bonds. Next, you can just combine weighted implied yield with weighted YTM, with corresponding weights.

Could you describe the futures part a bit more? Let's say I have 100 dollars in 1 bond with a yield of 10 % and a exposure of 100 dollars in a bond future with a implied yield of 5 %..
Is my portfolio yield then 10 + 5 = 15 %, or 0.5 * 10 + 0.5 * 5 = 7.5 %?

You compute weighted implied yield for futures in the same way as for bonds. Weight of future $i$ should be equal to market value of future $i$/total market value of futures. Now, you need to combine the weighted implied yield with weighted YTM. You just take arithmetic average of yields with the following weights: for bonds - total market value of bonds/(total market value of bonds + total market value of futures); for futures - total market value of futures/(total market value of bonds + total market value of futures).

Referring back to your example: should be (100/200)*10% + (100/200)*5% = 7.5%.

I was wondering if it should not just be 10 %? From the perspective of an investor, if you buy into this portfolio, then when the bond future matures, the bond future will mature and most likely will be rolled over into a new future (i.e. you never take delivery). Then isn't the actual yield 10 % and not 7.5 %?

Note, you should use market value of the futures contracts rather than their quoted futures price!

But implied yield is 5%, right?

Yes, but that's only if you actually take delivery of the underlying CTD bond at maturity date for the futures price (* CF + AI, etc).
What if I just cash-settle my bond future and roll it over into a new one? Then I'm not making (on average) any money on my bond future?

The implied yield of the futures contract (5% in your example) reflects the yield of the underlying bond implied by the futures price. However, this yield is tied to the price of the futures contract and is not realized unless you actually take delivery of the bond. So when we compute weighted portfolio, we assume you take delivery of the bond. However, if the strategy involves rolling over futures contracts rather than taking delivery, the effective yield of the futures component does not directly impact the portfolio’s yield in the same way as holding an actual bond.

If you roll over futures contracts continuously, the implied yield of the futures (5% in your case) might not be directly realized as a return. Instead, futures prices and their implied yields fluctuate based on market conditions.

If you are rolling over the futures and not taking delivery, your portfolio yield is primarily determined by the bond's yield. The futures contract serves as a hedge or a way to gain exposure to interest rates, but does not contribute to the income directly received if it is not held to maturity or cash-settled.

Related question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/80072

Bond Futures in a Bond Portfolio do not contribute to yield, they are there to modify (increase or decrease) Duration (or DV01 if you prefer). In my opinion they could be left out of the calculation of weighted YTM. They certainly should be taken into account for DV01, however.

I buy the argument from @nbbo2 that futures change DV01 but not yield (although you might need to think a bit about the margin; that's something I know nothing about but it always seems to be something you have to consider.)
As a thought, when we calculate YTM of a coupon bond, we basically decompose it into zero-coupon bonds (ZCBs) representing the coupons and the face value, and numerically find the single rate that would make the sum of all the ZCBs equal the market price. We could probably do the same for the whole portfolio (find the single rate for all payments across all holdings that makes the sum of ZCBs match the portfolio's market value).
I can't imagine that procedure would give a value hugely different from the weighted averages given above, however, so if I already had all the YTMs for each bond, I'd use the weighted average with the caveat that it might not be exactly the same.

You make a good point. The weighted YTM is NOT EQUAL to the Ytm of the cash flows from all the bonds, Though it seems to be what funds compute and advertise; no one I know computes the YTM of the cash flows from all the exected coupon and principal payments. I guess it is considered "good enough" to do the weighted average, though mathematically flawed.

YTM is pretty poor to start with. It makes the assumption of reinvested coupons at potentially unachievable levels. Even worse comparing different bonds assumes different reinvestment rates based on their ytm (i.e. on a steep curve). If you are going to derive some weighted YTM then this method seems as good as any. When accounting for leveraged positions financed by repo this might make the calculation more difficult.

Suppose, for example, that we invest 50% of my portfolio into a ZCB maturing in 6 months, and the other 50% in junk bond maturing in 10 years, paying some high coupon rate. When calculating the yield of this portfolio's combined cash flows, as you suggest, and the ZCB matures, do we assume that  it becomes cash, or rolls into a similar ZCB, or into the junk bond? Just the weighted average of the yields avoids needing to think about such decisions.
